# Calculate business hours between two dates by excluding non business hours in pandas data frame

Tags: python-datetime

I have two columns with start time and end time. I want to calculate difference between these two columns and exclude non-business hours. Business hours start on Monday 2:30 AM and ends on Saturday 6:30 AM.

Monday and Saturday has different business hours than Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday & Friday
Business hours on Monday starts at 2:30 and ends at 24:00 and for rest days starting Tuesday till Friday starts at 00:00 and ends at 24:00
Business hours on Saturday starts at 00:00 and ends at 7:00

[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrxDn.png)

[1st Output- where difference will be calculated for each row excluding non-business working hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5UI5.png)

[2nd Output- Will filter based on state and add all the calculated hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRmRa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2tI8.png)

Comment: Kindly help with the probem

Comment: Kindly help with the probem